# Notificaciones push para una web

Tags: web, push-notification

Quiero poder enviar notificaciones push a una web estilo Facebook. Es decir sin que el cliente (web) pregunte le lleguen notificaciones iniciadas por el servidor. Estaba pensando hacer la comunicación con sockets, pero me surge la duda de como hace Facebook para que te lleguen notificaciones aún con la página cerrada (al menos en Chrome).

Comment: Buena pregunta! ¿algún tipo de extensión instalada por defecto alomejor?

Comment: Aquí creo que tienes respuesta a tu pregunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687298/how-to-send-push-notification-to-web-browser

Comment: Te recomiendo esta página [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com)

Answer (score 1):

Las notificaciones push se dan gracias a una base de datos real-time que envían una aviso al navegador, en el caso de que las pagina web este cerrada, estas usan service workers(trabajadores de servicio) los cuales de almacenan en la cache, estos trabajadores son archivos javascript que se registran cuando las web es cargado por primera vez, posteriormente son activados cuando la base de datos real-time envié un aviso al navegador, una de las bases de datos real-time es Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client 
te recomiendo leer este articulo podrás entender mejor como funciona:https://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/notificaciones-push-web-firebase.html